# Copy, order and group data by certain rules (Create a transportation service sheet)

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

everyday I have to order and group a list of clients into several transport services, regarding their arrivals. So from the airport to their booked hotels.

Here is a link to an example file with that list at the sheet named: "chegadas". 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlcj9o1le44b2my/Transporte%20do%20aeroporto.xls?dl=1

The process is the following:

1- Order from A to Z by column VOO ( which is ARRIVAL FLIGHT data)

2- Group by hotel area (at "hoteis info" sheet)

3- Group until 8 pax (max veicule capacity)

4- Create shortest route between airport (starting point) and hotels of each service.

Sheet "chegadas-2" has a example of steps 1 to 3.

For step 4 I thought of creating a distance matrix (like at sheet "distâncias" - missing some hotels).
And use a solution like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E3rSoClgMI

I know I could group by hours with a pivottable as at sheet "Chegadas TD", however I still need to divide by 8 pax and order rows to make best route.

Is this possible to do this in Excel automatically with VBA and/or formulas??
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.Yes, look for Autofilter sort code seq that bests suits you. IE:

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

**2,3**.Best practice is not to use spaces in sheets, try to rename "hoteis_info", probably best approach here would be copy unique groups in a specific column there as horizontal titles, then loop through them for the persons in the VOO column and at the same time count if there are more than 8. Something like this:

```
Sub GroupbyHotel()
'assuming VOO is in Col 1
'assuming Hotel is in Col 2
Dim ColVOO As Long: ColVOO = 1
Dim ColHoteis As Long: ColHoteis = 2
Dim PaxName As String
Dim CounterPax As Long
Dim PaxInVehicle As Long
Dim FoundHoteis As Range
Dim RangeUnique As Range
Const SheetHoteis = "hoteis_info"
Const SheetARRIVAL_FLIGHT = "ARRIVAL_FLIGHT"
    Sheets(SheetARRIVAL_FLIGHT).Columns(ColHoteis).Copy Destination:=Sheets(SheetHoteis).Range("A1")
    With Sheets(SheetHoteis) ' 1. With Sheets(SheetHoteis)
    Set RangeUnique = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    RangeUnique.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    RangeUnique.Copy
    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Columns("A:A").Clear
    End With ' 1. With Sheets(SheetHoteis)
    With Sheets(SheetARRIVAL_FLIGHT) ' 2. With Sheets(SheetARRIVAL_FLIGHT)
    For CounterPax = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, ColVOO).End(xlUp).Row
    PaxName = .Cells(CounterPax, ColVOO).Value
    Set FoundHoteis = Sheets(SheetHoteis).Rows(1).Find(What:=.Cells(CounterPax, ColHoteis).Value)
    With Sheets(SheetHoteis) ' 3. With Sheets(SheetHoteis)
    PaxInVehicle = .Cells(Rows.Count, FoundHoteis.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    If PaxInVehicle Mod 9 = 0 Then ' 1. If Mod PaxInVehicle Mod 9 = 0 'this works to assign 8 passengers per vehicle (9th row would be the blank divisor)
    .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, FoundHoteis.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 2, FoundHoteis.Column).Value = PaxName '+2 to leave the blank among car assignments
    Else ' 1. If Mod PaxInVehicle Mod 9 = 0
    .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, FoundHoteis.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1, FoundHoteis.Column).Value = PaxName 
    End If ' 1. If Mod PaxInVehicle Mod 9 = 0
    End With ' 3. With Sheets(SheetHoteis)
    Next CounterPax
    End With ' 2. With Sheets(SheetARRIVAL_FLIGHT)
End Sub
```

**4**.This is known as ["Shortest path"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). You would need more research and to understand the logic behind it. Once you have done that, you may proceed to formulate a sub for it or go here for the [Solver Add-In](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/shortest-path-problem.html) that precisely does that. 
This is my suggested workflow model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer... And to check if sum of pax is 8, I should do a cycle through the cells and when the sum is >8 I will insert a blank line...  Honestly I dont know how to do that, If you can recommend some reading or example I would be thankfull...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use some sort of VLOOKUP to compare and calculate the shortest route.

http://excelcount.com/howto/how-do-i-retrieve-the-second-occurrence-with-vlookup/